# Share the same reusable FXML component in multiple views

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have a FXML view that contains a TabView with multiple tabs.
Every Tab has it's own FXML component + controller.

I would like all tabs to report progress via a component defined defined in the main view.

I know that I can inject child controllers into the main controller via FXML.

But to my current understanding, I need to access the parent controller inside my child controllers since the component is located in the main view.

I can also access the child controllers inside the initialize method of my main view. If I follow this path, I would need to modify the child controllers to set the shared component.
This is suboptimal, since the child components would be dependent on a main view that is performing those changes.

I created a MWE to illustrate the dilemma.

**The question in short:
How can I report progress of Service1 and Service2 to the progressAndStatusGrid in the main view?**

**Callenge in short:
Make this application not throw a NPE and report progress to the progress component ;)**

MWE:

Launcher:

```
package org.example;

public class Launcher {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SimpleApplication.main(args);
    }
}
```

Application:

```
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SimpleApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/MainView.fxml"));
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        MainViewController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
        final Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

MainController:

```
package org.example;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MainViewController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    GridPane progressAndStatusGrid;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    }
}
```

MainView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<BorderPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="350.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17.0.2-ea"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.example.MainViewController">
    <padding>
        <Insets top="4" right="4" bottom="4" left="4"/>
    </padding>
    <top>
    </top>
    <center>
        <TabPane>
            <Tab text="tab1" closable="false">
                <fx:include fx:id="tab1" source="Tab1View.fxml"/>
            </Tab>
            <Tab text="tab2" closable="false">
                <fx:include fx:id="tab2" source="Tab2View.fxml"/>
            </Tab>
        </TabPane>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <fx:include fx:id="progressAndStatusGrid"
                    source="ProgressAndStatusGridComponent.fxml"/>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

"Shared" componentController:

```
package org.example;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ProgressAndStatusGridComponentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @FXML
    HBox progressStatusBox;

    @FXML
    Label progressLabel;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {


    }


}
```

"Shared" componentView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<GridPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
          fx:controller="org.example.ProgressAndStatusGridComponentController"
          hgap="4" vgap="4">
    <padding>
        <Insets top="4" right="4" bottom="4" left="4"/>
    </padding>
    <fx:define>
        <ColumnConstraints fx:id="colConstraints2" percentWidth="100"/>
    </fx:define>
    <columnConstraints>
        <fx:reference source="colConstraints2"/>
        <fx:reference source="colConstraints2"/>
    </columnConstraints>
    <ProgressBar fx:id="progressBar" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
    <HBox fx:id="progressStatusBox" alignment="CENTER" spacing="4" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
        <padding>
            <Insets top="4" right="4" bottom="4" left="4"/>
        </padding>
        <Label fx:id="progressLabel"/>
    </HBox>
</GridPane>
```

Tab1Controller:

```
package org.example;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Tab1Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    Button button1;

    Service1 service1 = new Service1();

    // How to get a reference, that is already initialized?
    @FXML
    ProgressAndStatusGridComponentController progressAndStatusGridComponentController;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        button1.disableProperty().bind(service1.runningProperty());
    }

    public void handleButtonClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        service1.cancel();
        service1.reset();

        progressAndStatusGridComponentController.progressBar.progressProperty().bind(service1.progressProperty());
        progressAndStatusGridComponentController.progressLabel.textProperty().bind(service1.messageProperty());

        service1.start();
    }
}
```

Tab1View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="org.example.Tab1Controller">

    <center>

        <Button fx:id="button1" text="Start Background Progress #1" onAction="#handleButtonClick"/>

    </center>

</BorderPane>
```

Tab2Controller:

```
package org.example;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Tab2Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    Button button2;

    Service2 service2 = new Service2();

    // How to get a reference, that is already initialized?
    @FXML
    ProgressAndStatusGridComponentController progressAndStatusGridComponentController;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        button2.disableProperty().bind(service2.runningProperty());
    }

    public void handleButtonClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        service2.cancel();
        service2.reset();

        progressAndStatusGridComponentController.progressBar.progressProperty().bind(service2.progressProperty());
        progressAndStatusGridComponentController.progressLabel.textProperty().bind(service2.messageProperty());

        service2.start();
    }
}
```

Tab2View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="org.example.Tab2Controller">

    <center>

        <Button fx:id="button2" text="Start Background Progress #2" onAction="#handleButtonClick"/>

    </center>

</BorderPane>
```

Service1:

```
package org.example;

import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class Service1 extends Service<Void> {

    static final int workLoad = 100;

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {

        return new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                updateMessage("Starting Task #1..");
                for (int i = 0; i < workLoad; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    updateProgress(i, workLoad);
                    updateMessage(i + " elements done");
                }
                updateMessage("Task #1 done!");
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Service2:

```
package org.example;

import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class Service2 extends Service<Void> {

    static final int workLoad = 100;

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {

        return new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                updateMessage("Starting Task #2..");
                for (int i = 0; i < workLoad; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    updateProgress(i, workLoad);
                    updateMessage(i + " elements done");
                }
                updateMessage("Task #2 done!");
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which illustrates the dilemma, so it can be reproduced easily via copy+paste with no change or addition.

Comment: What should the progress and status report when both services are running at the same time?

Comment: Very valid point! Since there can be only one tab opened at the same time, the progress should show the progress of the currently opened tab. But I understand that this is difficult to achieve, since the task might run longer than I keep the tab open.. didn’t think about it to be honest :|

Comment: mind the __M__ please

Comment: Use a MVC approach, instead of trying to communicate directly between controllers.

Comment: > How can I report progress of Service1 and Service2 to the progressAndStatusGrid in the main view? 
Just use messages for the purpose.